# async class methods stopped working, why?

Tags: javascript, react-native, ecmascript-6, async-await

Following code (a class method declared as async) used to work:

```
    async reload() {
        const {
            resetState,
            getPhotos,
            uploadPendingPhotos,
        } = this.props
        await resetState()
        await getPhotos()
        await uploadPendingPhotos()
    }
```

After upgrading to the latest

```
"react-native": "0.59.8"
```

had to rewrite it to the following version to make it work again:

```
    reload() {
        const {
            resetState,
            getPhotos,
            uploadPendingPhotos,
        } = this.props
        resetState().then(() => {
            getPhotos().then(() => {
                uploadPendingPhotos()
            })
        })
    }
```

Otherwise it would complain about unfulfilled promise and complain about resetState method being read-only.

Any ideas what's going on here? I have async methods in most of my components, and rewriting them to promises is not feasible solution. I really do want to benefit from async/await.

Comment: Btw, it would be `resetState().then(() => getPhotos()).then(() => uploadPendingPhotos())` no need to extra-nest it

Comment: @zerkms then you should also be able to do resetState().then(getPhotos).then(uploadPendingPhotos)

Comment: Yeah, I understand, this is just a very simplistic example. I have much more complex code that does require nesting, which would be much harder to maintain comparing to the await.

Comment: @jonathanHeindl depending on how those functions are implemented it might behave differently: eg when those use `arguments` for any reasons.

Comment: Not sure what does it have to do with the arguments.